# Can not load the images in Java Swing when running from a .jar-file

Tags: java, image, swing, jar, classpath

I can run my Java Swing application from Eclipse without problems. But when I run it from a .jar-file, the images fails to load.

I load my images with:

```
setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().
getImage(getClass().getResource("../images/logo.png")));
```

How can I load the images so they work even when I'm running from a .jar-file?

The images is in the same Jar-file, in the packet `com.example.images` and the class where they are used is in `com.example.gui.dialogs`

Comment: You can bet the problem is with the path you give it.
First, you'd better use an absolute path, rather than relative one.
Second, make sure that the path is absolutely correct, including lowercase/uppercase, because although Windows File system is not case-sensitive, "JAR file system" IS case-sensitive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the absolut path inside your jar. If you don't know it, try opening the JAR with a zip programm, e.g. 7zip. Then use the absolute path:

```
getClass().getResource("/com/examples/images/logo.png")
```

This obiously only works when your image is in your jar. If its not, but in your classpath, this should be fine too.

Answer (score 1):

The images should be packed as well in a jar file. Actually, I'm not 100% sure there is no other solution, but at least I made it work this way, when experimenting the same issue.

The jar was then added to the classpath, and I'm accessing image resources this way:

`getResource("images/logo.png");`

Comment: @Jonas - Make sure their folder is correctly added to the classpath.