# i am not able to get the images read in java for exporting it as JAR

Tags: java, swing, executable-jar

This code throws a `NullPointerException` and I have no idea why.

```java
try {
    imageIcon = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("res/Background.png")));
    backgroundImage = imageIcon.getImage();
    signIn = new MyButton("SignIn", ImageIO.read(new File("res/SignIn.png")), ImageIO.read(new File("res/SignInHover.png")));
    signUp = new MyButton("SignUp", ImageIO.read(new File("res/SignUp.png")), ImageIO.read(new File("res/SignUpHover.png")));
    back = new MyButton("Back", ImageIO.read(new File("res/Back.png")), ImageIO.read(new File("res/BackHover.png")));
    exit = new MyButton("Exit", ImageIO.read(new File("res/Exit.png")), ImageIO.read(new File("res/ExitHover.png")));
} catch(IOException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "");
}
```

`res/` is a source folder in the project root which contains all images used in this piece of code but I'm not able to get it to work. I've tried using `getClass().getResource()` (which works from inside Eclipse but not from a .jar file) and `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` (which throws an exception telling that the input stream is null) but to no avail.

P.S.: `MyButton` is a user-defined class which extends `JButton` and has a constructor `MyButton(String, final BufferedImage, final BufferedImage)`.

Comment: maybe `SignIn.png` is in the `/res` directory like other assets?

Comment: Yes, each and every PNGs are inside /res which is at the same level as src and is the source folder for the project

Comment: so why you are trying to open `/SignIn.png`, not `res/SignIn.png`?

Comment: Actually Its my mistake coping the code.. I was trying each and every possible way to access it . but neither of them worked. Errors is coming from the ImageIcon line..

Comment: this is what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927334/can-not-load-the-images-in-java-swing-when-running-from-a-jar-file?rq=1

Comment: I've been gone through every question on stackOverflow. Neither of them worked for me. Thats why I created my own question here!

Comment: Don't use file based references to try and access resources such have been embedded within the application context, instead use , for example ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/res/SignIn.png"))

Comment: getResource will return null when the resource cannot be found, make sure the path is correct, also remember, unless the path starts with "/", the path will be relative to the class trying to load the resources, also, unzip the zip the jar file and make sure the images are where you expect them to be

Comment: Should I do it like this way?

Comment: ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/res/Background.png");

Answer (score 0):

> After all I succeeded by just making images folder under my source(i.e. under res) folder. And using method

`ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/SignIn.png"));`